# how to get miglayout-swing in gradle

Tags: gradle, miglayout

I am trying to get the miglayout jar file: `miglayout-3.7.2-swing.jar`.

I want only this jar. I don't want all the jars of `miglayout-3.7.2`.

If I give `com.miglayout:miglayout:3.7.2@jar` it downloads everything.

Any one help me how to download `miglayout-3.7.2-swing.jar` in gradle?

Comment: Can i give something like this ... runtime group: 'org.somegroup', name: 'somedependency', version: '1.0', classification: 'swing'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer!!

com.miglayout:miglayout:3.7.2:swing@jar    swing must be next to version. i tried before the version! :)